# How to return an array from properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var lanes = [
{
 "name" : "Breakfast Special",
 "className" : "breakfast-special",
 "sales" : 200,
 "redemptions" : 137
},
{
 "name" : "Free Danish",
 "className" : "free-danish",
 "sales" : 300,
 "redemptions" : 237
},
{
 "name" : "Half Price Coffee",
 "className" : "half-price-coffee",
 "sales" : 240,
 "redemptions" : 37
}];
```

I want to create an array that contains only numerical values stored for 'redemptions'. I can access values as:

```
lanes[0].redemptions;
```

By going through each object using a loop, but I am looking for some efficient way to do that.

I tried this using map function as follows:

```
var arrayRedemptions = lanes.map(function () {return this.redemptions});
```

But it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are object literals, not "JSON objects". It is a fairly [common misconception](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2):

You are quite close.

use

```
var arrayRedemptions = lanes.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.redemptions
});
```

Comment: Got it, the error was, I had some empty objects in the array. Fixed it like this:                                                                   var arrayRedemptions = lanes.map(function(obj) {
  if (obj) {
   return obj.redemptions;
  } else {
   return -1;
  }
 });

Comment: you just check: 
return obj && obj.redemptions

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Sorry didn't get your comment. What does that mean?

Comment: no problem @user3130733. if obj equals undefined or null map returns it. It is for   your prev comment(which is that: Got it, the error was). Also, i edited my answer

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!! @SheraliTurdiyev

Answer (score 2):

yeah. inside of map you can use these params(each **item, index, array**)

```
var arrayRedemptions = lanes.map(function (item, index, array) {
    return item ? item.redemptions : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after adding extra check especially while working with Auto Generated Content:

```
var arrayRedemptions = array.map(function(obj) {
    if (obj) 
        return obj.redemptions;
    else
        return -1;
});
```